# Position with one of the textbox in between textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question for positioning one of the textbox between textboxes in windows forms.

This below image:

[image]

From this code:

```
this.textBox2.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - this.textBox2.Width) / 2; // Description text box
```

And this below image:

[image]

From this code:

```
this.textBox2.Left = this.textBox2.Right / 2; // Description text box
```

My question is: How can I get the width of the description textbox, so there is only 20 pixels (probably) space between the quantity textbox and the price textbox? Like the two images above, the right and the left side of the description textbox.

You answer much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just set the distance in the designer, then anchor left and right and top.  Anchor your Price box just to the right and top.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the layout.

Create a layout with four columns:

1. Fixed width (product code)
2. Fixed width (quantity)
3. 100% (description)
4. Fixed width (price)

You have to set the `Anchor` for the controls to `Left,Right` so they size with their content. (You could probably fix the rest of your form in it too, if that is convenient to you)

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir @Patrick Hofman, I will try it. But, then if let's say the image on the question above is 1366 x 768 resolution, what happen if it is on 1920 x 1080 resolution sir? Does the textboxes follow the width of the resolution also? Because right now I can't test it on 1920 x 1080 resolution, just 1366 x 768